# More Efficient OR Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I currently have C# code checking for user input as such:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && InputTextbox.Text.Contains("good morning")
   ||
    e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && InputTextbox.Text.Contains("morning"))
```

Is there another way to use the || "or" statement so that it can all be in the one line? Something like:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && InputTextbox.Text.Contains("good morning" || "morning")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, for instance: if your InputTextBox is: "Hello good morning" I don't think the above answers will work, if this is what you seek (having a posibly larger string checked against the given smaller strings), you have to check it the other way around:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && (InputTextbox.Text.Contains("good morning") || InputTextbox.Text.Contains("morning"))
```

Just thought I'd point it out, if not the case ignore this answer.

Comment: I've used this method. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
var allowedText = new List<string> { "good morning", "morning" };

if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && allowedText.Contains(InputTextbox.Text))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an array with the values you want to check and then check if the array contains the TextBox value

```
string[] a = {"good morning" , "morning");

if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && a.Contains(InputTextbox.Text))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sufficient:

```cs
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && InputTextbox.Text.Contains("morning"))
{
}
```

It is because if `InputTextbox.Text.Contains("good morning")` is `true`, `InputTextbox.Text.Contains("morning")` must be `true` as well.